# How do I return firestore result in svelte?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte

How do you get the result from this in svelte into the page:

```
async function getCities(db) {
  const citiesCol = collection(db, 'cities');
  const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
  const cityList = citySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  return cityList;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Svelte code where you want show the retrieved data ?

Comment: Like a list or just strings, on the page. Doesn't matter. I can't get cityList out of that function. Supposed to be an array, right?

Comment: In svelte you can await for the async getCities function. See this example: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks

Comment: @voscausa Thanks. That helped me one step further.

Comment: Another method is to wrap the query in a readable store. Lets call te store cityList. In your page you can use $citylist to read the store. Here is an example:  Calling API inside readable store:  https://www.eternaldev.com/blog/introduction-to-svelte-readable-store/

Comment: @PålBergström Would you mind updating your question with the step further you have taken so we may continue to help you?

Comment: @fabc Thanks. I solved it. It is an array so I can loop through it but had to use await on the page to wait for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @voscausa I solved it. Had to use await https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks.

```
let cities = getCities();

{#await cities}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then cities}
  {#each cities as city}
      {city.name}
  {/each}
{:catch error}
    
{/await}
```